# window.open() does not work in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm working on an application where I need a window to be open in the browser when user clicks the button. But I get some errors after done() complete.
I am not sure that this is knockout.js issue but I suppose that it is:

I have this knockout action in js file:

```
function SaveBankCard(vm) {
if (viewModel._isBankCardChange()) {
    var modelJs = viewModel.BankCard.ToJS();

    return $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "../Profile/Save",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            currentCards: modelJs.Items,
            workerId: viewModel.Main.WorkerId()
        })

    })
        .done(function (changes) {
            viewModel._hashBankCardOld(viewModel.BankCard.GetHash());
            ShowSuccessContainer('Saved');

            if (changes.MemoAdded) {
                var url = '../Profile/Download?workerId='+ viewModel.Main.WorkerId();
                window.open(url, '_blank');
            }
        });
}

}
```

By some reason the url Profile/Download?workerId= is not opened on production environment (even when changes.MemoAdded is true). However, on test site it is working...

In Chrome Developer Tool I get the following errors:

---

(WEB_PAGE context) Lazy require of app.binding did not set the binding field

(WEB_PAGE context) Lazy require of webstore.binding did not set the binding field

(WEB_PAGE context) Lazy require of runtime.binding did not set the binding field

Uncaught Natives disabled

Uncaught Natives disabled

(WEB_PAGE context) extensions::event_bindings:8: Uncaught Natives disabled{}

(WEB_PAGE context) extensions::binding:5: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Event' of undefined{TypeError: Cannot read property 'Event' of undefined
    at extensions::binding:5:38
    at extensions::runtime:7:28}

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Binding' of undefined
    at extensions::runtime:7

---

I don't understand what these messages mean.

Any thought would be very appreciated ... I use knockout-3.3.0

**UPDATE**: these messages appears in Google Chrome (62.0.3202.94), Firefox is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omg, I just need to refresh the web page with Ctrl + F5.